# In Java, How to send continuous Data to multiple consumers from one producer?

Tags: java, spring-boot, architecture, cloud, spring-kafka

Problem statement :

1. I have one server which is continuously producing prices. This code is written in Java with spring boot.
2. I have multiples consumer servers / java programs which are running on different systems. Who will use prices which was produced by first producer server.

Question : In one milliseconds, I will produce around 300-400 prices (data). So Which is the best way to transfer continuous data from one producer server to multiple consumer servers ?

Data sice : hardly some kbs.

I researched on google and come to know some answers :

1. I can create one kafka producer who will produce prices and will send prices on some topics where other kafka consumers will receive/consume the same price on the same topic .
2. I can write prices in one database table and other consumers will read the prices from same table.
3. I can use some cloud consept where I will post prices on some cloud platform and from their consumers programs will read the prices.

So which is the better way from among three of us or if you have any other architecture so please help me in this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This isn't really on-topic for for Stack Overflow, because it asks for opinion based answers. However, to me, Kafka seems like a good fit for this.

Answer (score 1):

Go With kafka!

1. with kafka you can scale independently on your producer and consumer by Load. During server failover or deployments, it will resume using "offset". if you plan to scale horizontally there is a nice concept of consumer groups.
2. if u plan using a database u will need to address the below points as a developer.

- Your consumers need to sync to the database at scheduled intervals.
- You need a mechanism to not consume the same data in horizontally scaled systems.

3. which cloud mechanism exactly?

- if as storage u will get same issues as 2.

Comment: Right now I don't have any answer about cloud platform but we can use any like aws and azure also.